# Cannot reference to a vector when creating a data frame using tibble

Tags: r, tibble

I would like to create a two-column data frame. The first column contains only one letter, while the second column contains several letters. The content in the second column is stored in a vector. I tried to use the `tibble` function from the `tibble` package, but it gave me strange results. The second column is the same as the first column.

```
library(tibble)

vec <- c("A", "B", "C")

tibble(
  vec = rep(vec[1], length(vec)),
  vec_new = vec
)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# vec   vec_new 
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     A    
# 2 A     A    
# 3 A     A
```

I tried to create the same data frame with the `data.frame` and `data.table` functions from the `data.table` package. The result is as expected. Please let me know why `tibble` generates strange results and what is the best way to fix it.

```
data.frame(
  vec = rep(vec[1], length(vec)),
  vec_new = vec
)
#   vec vec_new
# 1   A       A
# 2   A       B
# 3   A       C

library(data.table)
data.table(
  vec = rep(vec[1], length(vec)),
  vec_new = vec
)
#    vec vec_new
# 1:   A       A
# 2:   A       B
# 3:   A       C
```

Comment: `tibble` allows for you to use variables as they are created. As soon as you create  column named `vec`, subsequent references to `vec` in the same `tibble()` call will assume you mean the just-created column, not the object in your global environment. You can either (a) use one of the alternates like `data.frame` or `data.table` or (b) don't use the same name for the object in your global environment and a column you are both creating and referencing when the column is not identical to the object in your global environment.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks. Please consider to turn your comment to an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the 'bang bang' notation to refer to objects outside of your tibble to prevent the 'issue' @Gregor Thomas mentioned in the comment of your post.

```
library(tibble)
tibble(vec = rep(vec[1], length(vec)),
       vec_new = !!vec)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  vec   vec_new
  <chr> <chr>  
1 A     A      
2 A     B      
3 A     C
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `.env` argument which can be used

```
library(tibble)
tibble(
  vec = rep(vec[1], length(vec)),
   vec_new = .env$vec
 )
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  vec   vec_new
  <chr> <chr>  
1 A     A      
2 A     B      
3 A     C
```